# How to remove "/app" from route in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have setup gatsby project and my routes only works when it contains `/app` because of this `gatsby` nodejs file.

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
  // only on the client.
  if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/app/*"

    // Update the page.
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

I need to remove `/app` from my all the components. Is it possible to do so?

And also on production mode my dynamic routes does not work what is the issue?

```
const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Router>
      <VerifyToken path="/app/:token"/>
      <MagicLink path="/app/link/:magicLink"/>
    </Router>
  </Layout>
)
```

Comment: @Towkir I have followed this tutorial https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/authentication-tutorial/

Comment: Ah, looks like it's about authentication. Thus, there are supposed to be some pages that requires authentication, and some don't. So, in order to restrict those pages, this mechanism is used. Read the second [paragraph](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/authentication-tutorial/#creating-client-only-routes) and you will understand. You must use some other words/strings instead of `/path` to implement this one.

Comment: @Towkir Could you give me an example of that?

Comment: @Towkir Well I authentication is not an issue here. Just want to remove "/app" from all the routes. Anyway thank you

Comment: is that all in your `gatsby-node.js` file ? if so, does your app work if you delete this file ?

Comment: @Towkir Only that routes work which are inside my `pages` folder.

Comment: well, how about you put all your pages inside that `pages` folder and also other folders like `pages/otherfolder/otherfile.js` ?

Comment: Also, try another thing, keep the `gatsby-node.js` file and remove the if condition `if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {` , and only keep the `createPage(page)` statement. whant happens then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192436/discussion-between-towkir-and-profer).

Comment: Did not work `remove the if condition if (page.path.match(/^\/app/))`

Comment: what about the comment above that ? did that work ? I mean moving all the pages into the `pages` directory and creating subdirectory ?

Comment: @Towkir It also did not work ;-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in your `gatsby-node.js` file is used to create what's called "[client only routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/authentication-tutorial/#creating-client-only-routes)". In the Gatsby docs they give an example that is used to create routes available only to logged-in users. These routes will exist on the client only and will not correspond to files in an app’s built assets on the server.

You could possibly eliminate the `/app` route if nothing is using it. But just based on the example component you posted, it does seem like your app is using it, and you did mention "dynamic routes". So you do need *something* to identify those routes and make them special to Gatsby.

In short, what this "client only route" is supposed to mean is that Gatsby will not create any server side pages for that route. But then you are supposed to create app components (mostly likely React components) that will respond to that route and build the content dynamically.

There is nothing special about the `/app` prefix. You can make it whatever you want as long as it is consistent between your Gatsby config and your client components and the router your client uses (hopefully Gastby's already built-in @reach/router?). But to create a hybrid app where some content is rendered server side by Gatsby and some content rendered dynamically client side, I'm pretty sure you need to have some kind of prefix to make that work so Gatsby can tell the difference between the two and how to render them. However, it's not clear from the [Gatsby docs on page matchPath](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/behind-the-scenes-terminology/#matchpath) how that works. From the code example in the Gatsby docs, it does take a regular expression. It's possible that instead of `/app` you could try to match some other string somewhere else in the path instead of being at the beginning of the path. Whatever you do, the client side router will need to be set up to match that route too.

I don't think the Gatsby docs are that great so I can understand your struggle trying to get this to work. This [Gatsby Mail App](https://github.com/DSchau/gatsby-mail) might help you to since it uses a different prefix (`/threads`) and has the complete source to an app that uses client side dynamic pages + static content.

> And also on production mode my dynamic routes does not work what is
>   the issue?

Very hard to tell with the limited code you provided. That doesn't look like it's the full source to that component. Is your component named `src/pages/app.js` or `src/pages/app/index.js`? That's what it needs to be named to handle the routing for the `/app` prefix.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer. I will award you the bounty until I don't get any other hidden surprise.

Comment: Let me know if you have any other questions or doubts and I will update the answer with extra info if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

To enable client-only routes with no prefix (no /app), you setup Gatsby as below.

In `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  if (page.path === `/`) {
    page.matchPath = `/*`
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

In `index.js`:

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Home path="/" />
      <OtherPage path="/other-page" />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. OP's was not working because the regex was matching any path starting with /, and the default page happens to be 404. You can either do a literal check as this post or tighten up your regex: `if (page.path.match(/^\/$/)) {`

Answer (score 0):

To remove /app from the route, you have to define your starting path named files in pages folder. For example, you want your home page to render with {your-domain}/home, just add a file named home.js in pages folder and import your component over there.

```html
import React from "react";
import HomePage from "../features/home/Home.index";


const Home = () => (
  <HomePage />
);

export default Home;
```